# Assign a new key to each object in the array with a unique id based on the index of the object in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to assign a new key to each object in the array with a unique id based on the index of the object in the array.

when I click a button it runs

```
    this.setState({ testStatus: "running", clicked: true });
    tests.map(test => {
      test.run(x =>
        this.setState({
          testStatus: {
            ...this.state.testStatus,
            [test.id]: x ? "passed" : "failed"
          }
        })
      );
    });
```

each test has a randomized delay and randomized Boolean result
When I console.log -> testStatus

it logs the following

```
0: "r"
1: "u"
2: "n"
3: "n"
4: "i"
5: "n"
6: "g"
undefined: "passed" <<<<---- variable outcome | undefined is what I want to have a unique id
```

```
**The array**
const tests = [
    { description: "Gochujang small batch live-edge green juice photo booth pinterest.",          run: testsResult() },
    { description: " DIY shaman narwhal before they sold out chambray aesthetic.",         run: testsResult() },
    { description: "Tousled cliche master cleanse, cray chicharrones fixie skateboard", run: testsResult() },
    { description: "Fanny pack keffiyeh coloring book hashtag 90's synth.",         run: testsResult() },
    { description: "Hexagon enamel pin artisan drinking vinegar.",  run: testsResult() },
    { description: "Knausgaard semiotics fashion axe occupy health goth",       run: testsResult() },
  ];
```

**The method**

```
  uniqueId() {
    let strKeys = Object.keys(tests);
    tests.map(test => {
      for (let index = 0; index < strKeys.length; index++) {
        let uniqId = (strKeys[index] = parseInt(strKeys[index]));
        Object.assign(test, { id: uniqId });
      }
    });
  }
```

the method is called with a click event handler.
like this

```
this.uniqueId();
```

before setting any state and such.

instead of assigning

it logs for eacht test the assigned value of testStatus [test.id] to an index key

like this

```
0: "r"
1: "u"
2: "n"
3: "n"
4: "i"
5: "passed" (variable)
6: "g"
```

Can someone point out my faulty logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `test.id` is there? or am I missing something

also `Object.assign` is meant to create a new copy of all the object properties inside, it does not mutate any of the objects

If you are trying to mutate `tests` to include id then
I'm not sure what you need `let strKeys = Object.keys(tests);` or `for (let index = 0; index < strKeys.length; index++) {` for though

but

```
uniqueId() {
    let strKeys = Object.keys(tests);
    tests = tests.map(test => {
      let newTest = {};
      for (let index = 0; index < strKeys.length; index++) {
        let uniqId = (strKeys[index] = parseInt(strKeys[index]));
        newTest = Object.assign(test, { id: uniqId });
      }
      return newTest;
    });
  }
```

I'm not going to try to understand why you need `let strKeys = Object.keys(tests);` or `for (let index = 0; index < strKeys.length; index++) {` though.

I feel like this probably does the same thing

```
uniqueId() {
    tests = tests.map((test, index) => {
        let uniqId = parseInt(index);
        return Object.assign(test, { id: uniqId });
    });
  }
```

Comment: there initially is no id on the tests array, each object has the keys description and run. 
I want to assign a unique id to each object in the array. 
so that I can set the testStatus to each tests id..

Comment: tests = tests.map etc.. is not necessary because tests is available in the state

Comment: `uniqueId() {
     tests.map((test, index) => {
        let uniqId = parseInt(index);
        return Object.assign(test, { id: uniqId });
    });
  }
` 
this fixed the unique ID problem

Comment: @newDev apologies, I was away

Comment: Yea @newDev the issue you faced was you were not returning to the `tests.map` basically

Answer (score 0):

Code is looking bit confused, but at least one obvious point is

in code below there's no sense to assign value for key **id** strKeys.length times, because only last one will be assigned after loop will finish

```
for (let index = 0; index < strKeys.length; index++) {
    let uniqId = (strKeys[index] = parseInt(strKeys[index]));
    Object.assign(test, { id: uniqId });
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what happens. 
after the loops runs, each test in the array has an id of 5 (makes sense, there are 6 tests)

Comment: but I don't get how I can assign each individual object a unique id based on their index (given the length is 6) I thought thought this way the first id would be 1 (instead of 0).